# Mercurial Install

Tags: vim, mercurial, ubuntu-12.04

I'm new to Linux (which I'm setting up to start teaching myself web development).  I am installing Vim, and in order to do so installed Mercurial.

hg clone https://vim.googlecode.com/hg vim   seemed to work fine, but when I try to update to the newest version using hg pull and hg update I get this after hg pull:

abort: no repository found in '/home/steven' (.hg not found)!

Am I doing something wrong?

Some details on my setup:
Dual boot computer with Windows on one SSD harddrive and Linux on a separate optical drive.
Ubuntu 12.04

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Don't worry if we close your post, it's just that this question should be asked on Super User rather than here.

Comment: Sorry, got a good reference so I don't continue to make these posting mistakes?

Comment: Sounds like you forgot to `cd vim` before running `hg pull`.

Comment: Installation/setup/compiling questions : Superuser, Search patterns/macros/general editing questions : Stakoverflow. I'd say.

Comment: The FAQ page for each site is linked to in the footer for the site and details what questions should be asked: [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) - [Super User](http://superuser.com/faq)

Answer (score 5):

1. You don't need Linux to learn Web dev: Windows and Mac OS X are equally fine.
2. You don't need to install Vim from the sources (and thus Mercurial) because it's already on your machine:

   1. summon the "Dash"
   2. type `ter`
   3. open *Terminal*
   4. type `vim` at the prompt and press `<Enter>`

   This CLI version of Vim is probably a "tiny" build which is going to lack a few useful features.

   A much proper Vim with a GUI frontend and more features is available through Ubuntu's package management system. To install it, you only need to launch *Ubuntu Software Center*, search for "gvim" and install it. This should be enough.

   If you need more control on the installation, you can install a second package manager called *Synaptic* which is less sexy than *Software Center* but a lot more detailed. In *Synaptic*, search for "vim-gnome" and/or "vim-nox".
3. To answer your question: the cloning created a "vim" directory in your "home": `/home/steven/vim` or `~/vim` (`~` being a shortcut for `/home/steven`). This "vim" directory is a self contained Mercurial repository and that's where you are supposed to issue any further Mercurial-related commands:

   ```
   $ hg clone https://vim.googlecode.com/hg vim
   $ cd vim <-- "change directory"
   $ hg something
   ```

   But *you don't have to do that:* the sources you get after the cloning are up to date and ready to be built.

Good luck and welcome on Linux (and SO).